# Make Thumbnail from Django ImageField.file and convert back to image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

So I have a form in Django that is used to upload an image to an ImageField.  This works well.  I then pass off the request.FILES['image'] off to a function called MakeThumbnail for further processing.

MakeThumbnail is not working too well. I have assembled this from a series of StackOverflow threads, but I think I am missing some crucial concepts.  Here is my code.

```
    def MakeThumbnail(file):
        img = Image.open(file)
        thumbnail = img.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        thumbnailString = StringIO.StringIO(thumbnail)
        newFile = ContentFile(thumbnailString)
        return newFile
```

The stacktrace says I am failing on this line:  newFile = ContentFile(thumbnailString).  It gives me the following error: expected read buffer, instance found

I think I might be failing back at thumbnail = img.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS), though, after looking at the local variables:

```
thumbnailString : <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x0000000003B39748>
file : <InMemoryUploadedFile: Desert.jpg (image/jpeg)>
thumbnail : None
img : <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=128x96 at 0x3B25C08>
```

Notice that thumbnail is none.  It should contain something.  Does anyone have some hints for me?

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you so much for the help, Jan Spurny. I figured it out with your help. So, when img is saved to thumbnailString, a few things need to happen. The code above actually produces an error because we pass an instance to ContentFile instead of a buffer.  No matter, we just need to call thumbnailString.read(). But thumbnailString.read() returns ''.  Turns out we need to do thumbnailString.seek(0) beforehand.  But this did not work either!

Ultimately, I was able to get the image file back to a Django file using InMemoryUploadedFile.

Here is what the code looks like, from beginning to end:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
import StringIO
def MakeThumbnail(file):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnailString = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(thumbnailString, 'JPEG')
    newFile = InMemoryUploadedFile(thumbnailString, None, 'temp.jpg', 'image/jpeg', thumbnailString.len, None)
    return newFile
```

Comment: hi! im very new to django and i would also like to add a thumbnail generation whenever an admin uploads an image. will i put this code on the model? thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the `img` to `StringIO.StringIO(img)`?

Comment: the img.save tag accommodates line of code takes care of this for us.  I'm not sure if passing a PIL Image object into StringIO would work out not.  My guess is that StringIO looks for a read method, which I assume the PIL Image implements, so I would imagine that solution would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

From PIL documentation about `Image.thumbnail`:

> Modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger
>   than the given size. This method calculates an appropriate thumbnail
>   size to preserve the aspect of the image, calls the draft method to
>   configure the file reader (where applicable), and finally resizes the
>   image.

That means your thumbnail is in `img`, not in `thumbnail` variable, because `Image.thumbnail` does not return anything (hence the `None`)

Another error is putting `PIL.Image` to `StringIO`. You'd better `save` it into `StringIO`

So your code should look more like this:

```
def MakeThumbnail(file):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnailString = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(thumbnailString, 'PNG')
    newFile = ContentFile(thumbnailString)
    return newFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the full path of the image to ur function and not the instance of the path.

```
EX:
models.py
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "logo"), null=True, default=None)

U need to pass
def MakeThumbnail(logo.path):
```